# how to Add Structure to Array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, structure

```
Private Structure Staff
    Public Name As String
    Public Number As Integer
    Public Total As Integer
    Public Status As String

End Structure

Dim Staffdata As Staff

Private Sub btnAddArray_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddArray.Click
    Dim strinfo As String


    Staffdata.Name = txtStaffmem.Text
    Staffdata.Number = txtStaffNum.Text
    Staffdata.Total = lblTotal.Text

    If radFullTime.Checked = True Then
        Staffdata.Status = "Full time"
    ElseIf radPartTime.Checked = True Then
        Staffdata.Status = "Part time"
    End If

    strinfo = ("Name: " & Staffdata.Name & ", Number: " & Staffdata.Number & ",Status: " & Staffdata.Status & ",Total sales: " & Staffdata.Total)
```

I want to this button to add those info to a array, how can i do that? In addition i need  add at least 5 staff members’ results using this structure and add them to an array.

Answer (score 2):

The common way is to override the `ToString` method in the structure.

```
Private Structure Staff

    Public Name As String
    Public Number As Integer
    Public Total As Integer
    Public Status As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Concat(
            "Name: ", Me.Name,
            ", ",
            "Number: ", Me.Number.ToString(),
            ", ",
            "Status: ", Me.Status,
            ", ",
            "Total sales: ", Me.Total.ToString()
        )
    End Function

End Structure
```

Store the data using a [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Private ReadOnly StaffData As New List(Of Staff)
```

In the click handle add a new item to the list.

```
Private Sub btnAddArray_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddArray.Click
    Me.StaffData.Add(New Staff() With {
        .Name = Me.txtStaffmem.Text,
        .Number = Integer.Parse(Me.txtStaffNum.Text),
        .Total = Integer.Parse(Me.lblTotal.Text),
        .Status = If(Me.radFullTime.Checked, "Full time", If(Me.radPartTime.Checked, "Part time", ""))
    })
End Sub
```

Now, if you want to create a single string containing all the items you can do as follows:

```
Dim all As String = String.Join("; ", (From item As Staff In Me.StaffData Let s = item.ToString() Select s))
```

Comment: +1 for the *professional* approach of `ToString` and a `List` rather than array.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `strinfo` as a string array to store the staff information. hence your code will be like:

```
Private Structure Staff
    Public Name As String
    Public Number As Integer
    Public Total As Integer
    Public Status As String
End Structure
Dim Staffdata As Staff
Dim stafCount As Integer=0 ' To calculate array index
Dim strinfo() As String ' Declare staff info as a string
Private Sub btnAddArray_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddArray.Click
    Staffdata.Name = txtStaffmem.Text
    Staffdata.Number = txtStaffNum.Text
    Staffdata.Total = lblTotal.Text
    If radFullTime.Checked = True Then
       Staffdata.Status = "Full time"
    ElseIf radPartTime.Checked = True Then
       Staffdata.Status = "Part time"
    End If
    strinfo(stafCount) = "Name: " & Staffdata.Name & ", Number: " & Staffdata.Number & ",Status: " & Staffdata.Status & ",Total sales: " & Staffdata.Total
    stafCount +=1 ' Increment array index
End Sub
```